# I want to modify my data in firebase but I am passing the property to be updated as an argument of a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to modify my data in firebase but I am passing the property to be updated as an argument of a function, but it's not working. please take a look at the code to better understand what I am trying to say.

```
export const updateGameData = async (uid, level, playerStar, moves) => {
  const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
  const data = {
    levels: {
      level: { star: playerStar, playerMoves: moves },
    },
  };
  try {
    await setDoc(userDocRef, data, { merge: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

As you can see I am passing level as an argument but it not taking the value of the level I passed as an argument when I use it as a property to create an Object. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you please post schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I believe `level` is a variable that should hold the **key** to push to, and not a value.

In JS, creating an object works like this:

```
const obj = {
  level: 1
}
```

Will create an object with a single key `a` that has value `1`.

What if we want a variable to hold the **key** to save to?

```
const level = 12

const obj = {
  level: 1
}
```

This doesn't change the output, because `level` is a literal string in this object definition. However if we wrap it in brackets like so: `[level]` inside the object definition...

```
const level = 12

const obj = {
  [level]: 1
}
```

We will have an object with a single key `12` that has value `1`.

This is because brackets as the key name will cause the JS expression inside the brackets to be evaluated and the expression should return a result that can then be used as key.

See [MDN computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) for a more detailed explanation.

You want your data defined like this:

```
const data = {
    levels: {
      // notice brackets
      [level]: { star: playerStar, playerMoves: moves },
    },
  };
```